# SQL statement inside while loop PHP

Tags: php, sql, loops, while-loop

I am trying to run a SQL statement within a while loop, using the variable $id set in the previous statement but am struggling to get it working. If I remove the statement in the while loop I can see the while loop is functioning as it displays the $id variable multiple times:

```
$businessPark = $_SESSION['businessPark'];
$num = "1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT CompanyId from Portal.services WHERE ".$businessPark."  = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $num);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->bind_result($id);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {

    echo "ID: " . $id . "<br>";

}
```

However when I add the SQL statement back in, I am presented with only the first $id result.  If I add in $stmt->close(); at the start of the while loop I do get the first company name, but then the while loops ends.  Here is the code:

```
$businessPark = $_SESSION['businessPark'];
$num = "1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT CompanyId from Portal.services WHERE ".$businessPark."  = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $num);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->bind_result($id);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {

    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT CompanyName from phpipam.ipaddresses WHERE id = ?");
    $sql->bind_param("s", $id);
    $sql->execute(); 
    $sql->bind_result($CompanyName);
    $sql->fetch();
    echo $CompanyName;
}
```

Any ideas please?

Update:  If I add in a store result before the loop and free result inside the loop I get the **first** company name and also get the "finished loop" echo:

```
    $businessPark = $_SESSION['businessPark'];
$num = "1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT CompanyId from Portal.services WHERE ".$businessPark."  = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $num);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->bind_result($id);
$stmt->store_result();
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
$stmt->free_result();
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT CompanyName from phpipam.ipaddresses WHERE id = ?");
$sql->bind_param("s", $id);
$sql->execute(); 
$sql->bind_result($CompanyName);
$sql->fetch();
echo $CompanyName;

}

echo "finished the loop";

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to access 2 different databases using the same connection? Is that what you are doing

Comment: you need different connection string for different database

Comment: @JYoThI not technically true - you can either reference the schema directly or use `mysqli::select_db()` to chop and change - different database **servers** however.

Comment: I don't see that you've set the ID variable, so maybe it's being set somewhere else?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out why this hasn't just fallen over with a `commands out of synch` error personally... I think I need more coffee.

Comment: Will your second select only ever produce one row?

Comment: It's the same database server.  Haven't had any issues connecting to different db's in the rest of my code as long as i've specified the name of the db before the table name but could be wrong...The second select should have the same number of results as the first.  All  IDs have a company name.

Comment: ___Just an observation:___ The second `->prepare` should really be outside(above) the while loop. Thats the point of prepare, you prepare once and reuse the prepared statement many times substituting new parameters each time

Comment: ___Second Observation:___ Is the `id` in the second query a string or an integer?

Comment: Couldn't you use a join here?

Comment: It's actually an integer but both statements works when I split them up.

Comment: @simon Possibly, however i'm not sure how. I do remember joins from back in the day but unsure how to execute that!  This (obviously) isn't my day job!

Comment: I've still got a niggly feeling there should be a `store_result()` before the while loop and a `free_result()` afterwards...

Comment: @CD001 I agree I feel like it's something like that, or that i'm not closing statements correctly.  If I add in a store_result() before the loop I do get the first company name so it is executing both SQL commands.  It just isn't completing the loop.

Comment: You *need* to move the 2nd prepared statement out of the loop - or you'll hit that error ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had it working (albeit with different queries) on my test server - I'm pretty sure the issue is that you need to pass the resultset through to PHP so that you can prepare the second statement (which *must* be outside the loop) - otherwise `sql = $conn->prepare( ... );` fails and returns `false`.

This *should* work:

```
$businessPark = $_SESSION['businessPark'];
$num = "1";

//first statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT CompanyId from Portal.services WHERE ".$businessPark."  = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $num);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->bind_result($id);

//pass the result to PHP so you can prepare a new statement
$stmt->store_result();

//second statement
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT CompanyName from phpipam.ipaddresses WHERE id = ?");

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $sql->bind_param("s", $id);
    $sql->execute(); 
    $sql->bind_result($CompanyName);
    $sql->fetch();

    echo $CompanyName;
}

//clean up
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Cant comment so answering here.

I think you need to use `$stmt->bind_param("s", $businessPark);` instead of `$stmt->bind_param("s", $num);`

Comment: I dont think this is right, he uses `$businessPark` to key the first select which gets him the `id` he want to use in the second select

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want with a join. I know that this does not answer why your code is not working but in my opinion it's a better solution anyway.

```
$businessPark = $_SESSION['businessPark'];
$num = "1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
SELECT t2.CompanyName
FROM Portal.services t1
INNER JOIN phpipam.ipaddresses t2 ON t1.CompanyId = t2.id
WHERE " . $businessPark . " = ?
");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $num);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->bind_result($companyName);
```

More information about [join syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)